# Create IMAP mailbox in linux server

Tags: linux, postfix, dovecot

I am using Postfix 2.10.2/Dovecot 2.2.5 on RHEL 5.9.
I used to create normal virtual mailboxes.

How can i create IMAP mailbox and use it and how to differentiate it from POP3 mailboxes ?

I hope i am asking the right question, if not please correct me.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enabled both POP3 and IMAP in the Dovecot configuration your users can choose either protocol to access their email. There is no difference for the mailbox, no additional preparation of the mailbox is required. With either protocol users will see the same email messages in the INBOX.

Of course POP3 doesn't support organizing messages in other folders/directories, it only knows the INBOX. And the client defaults are often to delete messages from the server after retrieval.

With IMAP messages remain on the server unless explicitly deleted and you can create other directories (common defaults are Draft, Trash and Sent) to organize your e-mail. The IMAP protocol is much better suited to have your users access their email from multiple devices and webmail.